# Ceiling fan installation light works fan won’t turn

Tags: ceiling-fan, installation

So I got a fan/light fixture and fixed it up. 
When I turn on the switch(I have just 1) only the light turns on. The fan doesn’t turn on. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: There's usually two separate wires inside the fixture to allow them to be connected to separate switches - typically they're blue and black, with the white being the common to neutral. Have you connected the two together for the common switch? Fixture instructions should tell you the details.

Comment: Are you sure the chain pull switch for the fan is "on? It's a high, medium and low speed switch